# Project B references project A which has a class using system.DirectoryServices ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have a Project B which references project A in the same solution. Project A has a class1 using system.DirectoryServices ASP.NET. I have added reference to System.DirectoryServices in Project A.
Now in my project B, I have a page1.aspx that tries to call class1 in project A. I get an error here. Page1.aspx.vb only tries to access a property of Class1, it does not try to access the DirectoryServices directly.
Why should I be adding a reference to System.DirectoryServices in Project B?

Indirect reference is being made to assembly 'System.DirectoryServices', which contains 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry'. Add a file reference to 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.DirectoryServices.dll' to your project.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a public method that returns or accepts any type defined in System.DirectoryServices, and you are consuming that method directly or indirectly from Project B, then you have to add a reference to System.DirectoryServices in Project B. Otherwise it shouldn't bother you at all.

If you don't want to add a reference to System.DirectoryServices in Project B at all, then consider Programming to an interface!! Abstract out the feature and work using interfaces, rather than referencing concrete types.

Comment: The class1 in Project A uses the System.DirectoryServices methods to populate its fields, and these Class1 fields are used by a page in Project B. According to me, only place I need to add reference to System.DirectoryServices should be in Project A, not in project B since it is not directly accessing it, it is just accessing a class in another project which uses it.

Comment: If those public fields in Class1 expose any type defined in System.DirectoryServices then you have to add a reference to it in the other project as well.

Comment: I just overlooked somehow the whole day today that a method that was populating those public fields was also returning DirectoryEntry. Changed it to a string and I don't have to add reference in Project B as it should be. Thanks Kaz-LA.